# On the second page of my PDF, the margin gets larger

Tags: margins, memoir

I'm not quite into this Latex yet, and I have a bit of a problem..
My preamble looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[danish]{babel} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} \usepackage{bm} \usepackage{amsthm} \usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Every time I get to the second page, the left margin on the PDF increases. When I've managed to write enough to fill 3 pages, the margin on the third page moves back to normal. So I only have this problem on the second page.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This sounds like a `binding offset` convention- if you have a look at a (paper copy) of a text book, you might notice that the margins are different for odd and even pages.

Comment: Expanding on @cmhughes comment: In most circumstances this is a desired feature - not an error.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen I have my doubts about this claim. Articles are usually typeset with equal margins at least prior to final typesetting for publication. I would never use unequal margins for submission to a journal, for example.

Comment: @cfr: You are correct. -I should have specified that the feature is for books(memoir is used for books and larger works). I just wanted the OP to know that it is not an error.

Answer (score 5):

Use a onesided document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,article,oneside]{memoir}
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand a little on Herbert's answer, what may be confusing is that `memoir`'s documentation says this:

> article typesetting simulates the article class, but the \chapter
>   command is not disabled. Chapters do not start a new page and chapter
>   headings are typeset like a section heading. The numbering of figures,
>   etc., is continuous and not per chapter. However, a \part command
>   still puts its heading on a page by itself.

Now when you use LaTeX's standard `article` class with

```
\documentclass{article}
```

`oneside` is *default*. To make an `article` two-sided, you have to specify the `twoside` option.

`memoir`, it seems, does things a little differently since the documentation also states that

> The defaults among the printing options are twoside, onecolumn,
>   openright, and final.

where these apparently apply even when the `article` option is passed to the class. So there is some inconsistency in describing this option as 'simulating the article class' and then not including the difference in printing defaults among the caveats.